# Change bash shell to look like the one on heroku demo

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

I am in love with the bash shell look and feel show in the intro video of heroku.
Anyone has got an idea how I can implement this kind of bash look :

[image]

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: I found this theme in `bash-it` https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it here are screenshots https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes. It was easy to install but did not work for me, shell was messed up after, you may have more luck.

Comment: That looks like powerline to me. See https://github.com/powerline/powerline.

Comment: I was searching for this as well. The closest thing is Powerline I guess.

Comment: Here you go guys, https://askubuntu.com/a/1086620/885455

Comment: I wonder why was this marked as a duplicate when the linked question is much later than this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme is called “**Wild Cherry**” — Get it from here, https://github.com/mashaal/wild-cherry

[image: Wild Cherry]